# How does the strength of 3D printed tendons compare to original tendons?

Tags: human-biology, tendons, 3d-bioprinting

There have been some attempts such as {1,2} to [3D-bioprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_bioprinting) tendons. How does the strength of 3D-bioprinted tendons compare to original tendons? I am mostly interested in human tendons.

---

References:

- {1} Ede, David, Nikki Davidoff, Alejandro Blitch, Niloofar Farhang, and Robby D. Bowles. "Microfluidic Flow Cell Array for Controlled Cell Deposition in Engineered Musculoskeletal Tissues." Tissue Engineering Part C: Methods 24, no. 9 (2018): 546-556. https://doi.org/10.1089/ten.tec.2018.0184
- {2} Rimann, Markus, Sandra Laternser, Hansjörg Keller, Olivier Leupin, and Ursula Graf-Hausner. "3D bioprinted muscle and tendon tissues for drug development." CHIMIA International Journal for Chemistry 69, no. 1 (2015): 65-67. https://doi.org/10.2533/chimia.2015.65 (open access)